# transfer json file to client

Tags: servlets, file-transfer

```
String objectToReturn = "{ key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }";
JsonObject json = new JsonObject(objectToReturn);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream());
dos.write(json.toString().getBytes());
dos.close();
```

upper code is for transfering json file to client. (actually i am server)
when i execute that code, the String 'objectToReturn ' is shown { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' } in the result page. i want it to be transferd as a stream file.
is it trasfered well? or not. what should i do?

Comment: so you want to make the receiver thing you are sending a file ? in php you would have to modifiy http headers to achives this and then simpley echo the output

Comment: What is a "stream file"?